# AS2 textWidth property

Tags: flash, google-chrome, actionscript-2

I am using a TextField in Flash CS2, because I need to know the width of the actual text for positioning purposes. However from some odd reason it doesn't always work when the browser is Google Chrome.

Did anyone came across this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with a particular version of the Adobe Flash Player. I updated it and fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember something like that from the AS2 times. Try waiting one frame before you measure the text, e.g. by setting a flag called `redrawNextFrame` to true, and in the `onEnterFrame` callback, if the flag is set, do your layout redraw (including text measurement) there, and unset the flag.